# Trying to use 'selectattr in' filter with Ansible playbook but it fails as per the playbook below

Tags: ansible, python-textfsm

I am trying to use textfsm to parse the data for admin show platform in that anything with a state of 'IOS XR RUN' 'READY' or 'OK' will pass & anything else will report failed. I'm using the selectattr in option but get the following error - "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'intf_tests_pass' is undefined. Any ideas why this is failing as the working_state variable is defined.

- name: Collect admin show platform info
    iosxr_command:
      commands:
        - admin show platform
      provider: "{{ cli }}"
    register: platform_result
    when: device_os == 'cisco-ios-xr'

  - name: retrieve status to be returned
    set_fact: 
     working_state: ['IOS XR RUN', 'READY', 'OK']
  - name: parse platform_result
    textfsm_parser:
    file: templates_textfsm/{{ device_os }}/admin_show_platform.template
    content: "{{ platform_result.stdout.0 }}"
    name: platform_state
    when:

    - platform_result.stdout is defined
    - platform_result.stdout[0] != none
    - platform_result.stdout[0] != ""
  - name: identify platform_result that passed
    set_fact:
    platform_tests_pass: "{{ ansible_facts.platform_state | 
    selectattr('STATE', 'in', 'working_state') | list }}"
    when:  ansible_facts.platform_state is defined
  - name: identify platform_result that failed 
    set_fact:
    platform_tests_fail: "{{ ansible_facts.platform_state | 
    difference(platform_tests_pass) | list}}"
    when: ansible_facts.platform_state is defined
  - debug:
    msg:

    - "{{ intf_tests_pass }}"
    - "{{ intf_tests_fail }}"

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: [Edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61390212/edit) to fix the formatting, since the formatting for ansible playbooks matters a great deal

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you posted, you saved facts to platform_tests_pass and platform_tests_fail, not intf_tests_pass and intf_tests_fail, so those variables are never actually defined.